# Tool to Monitor Serial Port in USRP2

Tags: gnuradio, system-generator

I am working on USRP2 and would like to read the debug messages. There is a serial port at the rear-end.

I connect a standard USB to 3.3v-level serial converter. But I am not sure, which tool to use to read the messages.

As per the specification, I could read the debug verbose message at  230400 baud.

Can we use Hyperterminal in Windows ? Any 3rd party tools or any tools in Linux would be helpful as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `minicom` in Linux, [Teraterm Pro](http://www.ayera.com/teraterm/) in Windows.

(In a pinch in Linux you can do something like `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` if you don't need to send anything back to your embedded system, and the default baud rate can be configured correctly...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, cat /dev/ttyUSB0 worked like a charm. But I am using minicom and cutecom.